# How to change the class of time column from character to POSIXct

Tags: r

How do I change the class of sleep_time and wake_time columns from character to POSIXct?(Dataset clip is attached below)

I tried this but it didn't work

```
data$sleep_time <- as.Date(data$sleep_time, format = "%h.%m.%s")
```

[image: Dataset clip]

Comment: You cannot change them. Unless you combine the `date` also. Consider using `data.table::ITime` class

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, e.g. `dput(head(data))`, in your question.

Answer (score 1):

First provide reproducible data using `dput()`:

```
data <- structure(list(date = "16-03-2022", sleep_time = "01.01", wake_time = "06.02"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
as.POSIXct(paste(data$date, data$sleep_time), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H.%M")
# [1] "2022-03-16 01:01:00 CDT"
as.POSIXct(paste(data$date, data$wake_time), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H.%M")
# [1] "2022-03-16 06:02:00 CDT"
```

See `?as.POSIXct` for details.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to convert to `POSIXct`, then you need to combine the time with the date. Here, we can `paste` the date and time together, then convert to `as.POSIXct`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(sleep_time = as.POSIXct(paste(date, sleep_time), format="%d-%m-%Y %H.%M"),
         wake_time = as.POSIXct(paste(date, wake_time), format="%d-%m-%Y %H.%M"))
```

**Output**

```
        date          sleep_time           wake_time
1 16-03-2022 2022-03-16 01:01:00 2022-03-16 06:02:00
2 16-03-2022 2022-03-16 23:07:00 2022-03-16 06:25:00
3 16-03-2022 2022-03-16 01:48:00 2022-03-16 08:23:00
```

If you are just wanting to get it into that time format, then you can convert the only keep the time, although it would just be character then.

```
df %>%
  mutate(sleep_time = format(strptime(sleep_time,format="%H.%M"), format="%H:%M:%S"),
         wake_time = format(strptime(wake_time, format="%H.%M"), format="%H:%M:%S"))

#        date sleep_time wake_time
#1 16-03-2022   01:01:00  06:02:00
#2 16-03-2022   23:07:00  06:25:00
#3 16-03-2022   01:48:00  08:23:00
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("16-03-2022", "16-03-2022", "16-03-2022"
), sleep_time = c(1.01, 23.07, 1.48), wake_time = c(6.02, 6.25, 
8.23)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```